# How to encode .yuv video using MPEG-2

Tags: video, video-encoding, mpeg-2

I am trying to encode akiyo_cif.yuv video file (resolution 352 x 288) (downloaded from http://trace.eas.asu.edu/yuv/akiyo/akiyo_cif.7z) using mpeg 2 encoder (version 1.1) downloaded from MPEG official site ( http://www.mpeg.org/pub_ftp/mpeg/mss...c_v1.1a.tar.gz).

Contents of parameter file are given below

```
MPEG-2 Verification Sequence
akiyo_cif    /* name of source files */
-        /* name of reconstructed images ("-": don't store) */
-         /* name of intra quant matrix file     ("-": default matrix) */ 
-         /* name of non intra quant matrix file ("-": default matrix) */
-         /* name of statistics file ("-": stdout ) */
1         /* input picture file format: 0=*.Y,*.U,*.V, 1=*.yuv, 2=*.ppm */ 
300         /* number of frames */
0         /* number of first frame */
23:59:59:24 /* timecode of first frame */
6         /* N (# of frames in GOP) */
2         /* M (I/P frame distance) */
0         /* ISO/IEC 11172-2 stream */
0         /* 0:frame pictures, 1:field pictures */
352       /* horizontal_size */
288       /* vertical_size */
2         /* aspect_ratio_information 1=square pel, 2=4:3, 3=16:9, 4=2.11:1 */
3         /* frame_rate_code 2=23.976, 3=25, 4=29.97, 5=30 frames/second */
400000.0  /* bit_rate (bits/s) */
6         /* vbv_buffer_size (in multiples of 16 kbit) */
0         /* low_delay  */
0         /* constrained_parameters_flag */
4         /* Profile ID: Simple = 5, Main = 4, SNR = 3, Spatial = 2, High = 1 */
8         /* Level ID:   Low = 10, Main = 8, High 1440 = 6, High = 4          */
0         /* progressive_sequence */
1         /* chroma_format: 1=4:2:0, 2=4:2:2, 3=4:4:4 */
1         /* video_format: 0=comp., 1=PAL, 2=NTSC, 3=SECAM, 4=MAC, 5=unspec. */
5         /* color_primaries */
5         /* transfer_characteristics */
5         /* matrix_coefficients */
352       /* display_horizontal_size */
288       /* display_vertical_size */
1         /* intra_dc_precision (0: 8 bit, 1: 9 bit, 2: 10 bit, 3: 11 bit */
1         /* top_field_first */
1 0 0     /* frame_pred_frame_dct (I P B) */
0 0 0     /* concealment_motion_vectors (I P B) */
0 1 1     /* q_scale_type  (I P B) */
1 1 0     /* intra_vlc_format (I P B)*/
1 0 1     /* alternate_scan (I P B) */
0         /* repeat_first_field */
0         /* progressive_frame */
0         /* P distance between complete intra slice refresh */
0         /* rate control: r (reaction parameter) */
0         /* rate control: avg_act (initial average activity) */
0         /* rate control: Xi (initial I frame global complexity measure) */
0         /* rate control: Xp (initial P frame global complexity measure) */
0         /* rate control: Xb (initial B frame global complexity measure) */
0         /* rate control: d0i (initial I frame virtual buffer fullness) */
0         /* rate control: d0p (initial P frame virtual buffer fullness) */
0         /* rate control: d0b (initial B frame virtual buffer fullness) */
2 2 11 11 /* P:  forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code search_width/height */
1 1 3  3  /* B1: forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code search_width/height */
1 1 7  7  /* B1: back_hor_f_code back_vert_f_code search_width/height */
1 1 7  7  /* B2: forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code search_width/height */
1 1 3  3  /* B2: back_hor_f_code back_vert_f_code search_width/height */
```

But I am not able to get desired output. It only shows the 1st frame of video for whole duration.

Can you suggest what is the problem .yuv file, parameter file, or anything else?

Comment: Does it work if you set it to encode only I frames?

Comment: We can. But it will make things worse. Because I frames are sent directly without motion estimation and compensation. so it will reduce compression drastically and we will get videowhich has size much much higher than that of desired

Comment: I understand that. One of the ways to debug is to encode all I frames to see if the problem goes away. If the problem does go away, then you know that problem is something to do with P frame parameters. Since you are using YUV and encoder implementation from the net, you may have a broken encoder problem. Hence the step-wise debug method is preferred.